# Trouble with getting value from a website - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i'm not searching to do something complicated , i just want to retrieve certain titles from a website , the first button was just for a test ... The thing is , even the "lala" text isn't showing up which means it doesn't enter in the loop in the first place ...

```
Public Class Form1
    Function ElementsByClass(document As HtmlDocument, classname As String)
        Dim coll As New Collection
        For Each elem As HtmlElement In document.All
            If elem.GetAttribute("appcenter").ToLower.Split(" ").Contains(classname.ToLower) Then
                coll.Add(elem)
            End If
        Next
        Return coll
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim wb As New System.Net.WebClient
        wb.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!")
        Dim sourceString As String = wb.DownloadString("http://www.ign.com/games/upcoming")
        RichTextBox1.Text = sourceString
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim elementss As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        For Each pElem As HtmlElement In elementss
            If pElem.GetAttribute("class") = "item-title" Then
                RichTextBox1.Text = "lala"
                RichTextBox1.Text = pElem.InnerHtml
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you just wanting the titles of each new upcoming game?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from what I can tell you are after the titles of each new upcoming game.
Something like this should do the trick for you.
I would recommend that for larger web scraps that you use the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
However since you are only wanting a few strings, this solution should be ok for you.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim websiteURL As String = "http://www.ign.com/games/upcoming"
    getTiles(websiteURL) 'where you access this is up to you
End Sub

Private Sub getTiles(website As String)

    ListBox1.Items.Clear() 'Clear old results or any errors

    Dim tempTitles As New List(Of String)()
    Dim webClient As New WebClient()
    webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "null")

    Try 'If the website happens to go offline, at least your application wont crash.
        Dim content As String = webClient.DownloadString(website)
        Dim pattern As String = "alt=""(?<Data>[^>]*)""/>"
        For Each title As Match In (New Regex(pattern).Matches(content)) 'Since you are only pulling a few strings, I thought a regex would be better.
            tempTitles.Add(title.Groups("Data").Value)
        Next
        Dim titles = tempTitles.Distinct().ToArray() 'remove duplicate titles

        For Each title As String In titles
            ListBox1.Items.Add(title) 'what you do with the values from here is up to you.
        Next

        If titles.Count() = 0 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Nothing Found")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have written some comments to go along with the code to answer any questions you might have.
If i have missed something out, feel free to leave a comment below, Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm , i didn't quite understand this following like : Dim pattern As String = "alt=""(?<Data>[^>]*)""/>" .Is this how you defined what String you should bring from the website ? Or ? :)

Comment: Not the guy but yes it's called regex, you can learn more about it from [here](https://regexone.com/).

Comment: I understand how it works now , i wanted to try it using this website as a source this time : http://www.gamestop.com/collection/upcoming-video-games and i wrote Dim pattern As String = "jpg""><p>""(?<Data>[^>]*)""<br>" but it didn't work , can you possibly tell me what i did wrong ?! :)

Comment: You'd have to be more specific, but you can test your regex [here](http://regexr.com/) by just pasting the source of the page here and then seeing the results your regex in realtime.

Comment: Thanks @EuX0 , i think now i'm a little bit closer to understanding all the code : so the results in RegExr i came up with was : .jpg"><p>?[^>]*<br> But when i used it in the code it doesn't work  , Dim pattern As String = ".jpg""><p>?<Data>[^>]*<br>" I think i'm missing something lol

Comment: And for exemple i have 113 match , the itemlist shows "The operation had timed out" , i think there is a limit for the matchs i can list ?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: are you wanting to download the pictures too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I suck at explaining these things so please analyze the regex in the site I mentioned in the comment earlier.

The site you specified lists the games like this:

```
<a class="product_spot " href="/browse?nav=16k-3-rime,28zu0" data-date="05/06/2017"><img src="/gs/pages/landing/upcoming-video-games/images/223x120_rime.jpg"><p>RiME<br><br><span>05/06/2017</span></p></a>
```

---

```
<a class="product_spot " href="/browse/games?nav=16k-3-the+surge,28zu0,13ffff2418" data-date="05/16/2017"><img src="/gs/pages/landing/upcoming-video-games/images/223x120_thesurge.jpg"><p>The Surge<br><br><span>05/16/2017</span></p></a>
```

---

So this regex will match that.

```
<a class=.product_spot\s.\shref=.(?:.+?)\sdata-date=.(?:.+?)><img\ssrc=(?:.+?)><p>(.+?)<br><br><span>(?:.+?)<\/span><\/p><\/a>
```

---

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim wc As New WebClient
        Dim input As String = wc.DownloadString("http://www.gamestop.com/collection/upcoming-video-games")
        Dim games As New List(Of String)
        Dim matchCollection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, "<a class=.product_spot\s.\shref=.(?:.+?)\sdata-date=.(?:.+?)><img\ssrc=(?:.+?)><p>(.+?)<br><br><span>(.+?)<\/span><\/p><\/a>")

       For Each item As Match In matchCollection
            games.Add(item.Groups(1).Value.ToString)
        Next

        For Each item As String In games
            Console.WriteLine(item)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output:

```
Dead Island 2
Final Fantasy XV
De-Formers
Injustice 2
...
Killing Floor 2
Tales of Berseria
Nintendo Switch
Mass Effect Andromeda
MLB The Show 17
Has-Been Heroes
Ride 2
...
..
.
```